In WPF, how do I determine the DPI values for RenderTargetBitmap?
I am trying to draw a bitmap onto an Image control in a WPF app. The image is defined as 800 x 800.
What I do is, I create a DrawingVisual, use RenderOpen() to create a DrawingContext, apply changes to the DrawingContext (in this case, draw alternating red and blue 98 x 98 rectangles), then create a RenderTargetBitmap of size 800 x 80 and some manually-entered DPI, call Render() on it, and set the Image's source to the bitmap.
The problem is, unless I know what the DPI is, the image does not render to the correct size. For some strange reason, the DPI appears to be somwehere around 91.
Here is the C# code that creates the image - note that, for the moment, I am hard-coding the DPIs as 96:
        DrawingVisual D = new DrawingVisual();
        DrawingContext DC = D.RenderOpen();
        DC.DrawRectangle(Brushes.White, null, new Rect(0, 0, 800, 800));

        int R, C;
        for (R = 0; R < 8; R++)
        {
            for (C = 0; C < 8; C++)
            {
                Brush TheColor = Brushes.Red;
                if ((R + C) % 2 == 0)
                {
                    TheColor = Brushes.Blue;
                }
                DC.DrawRectangle(TheColor, null, new Rect(C * 100 + 1, R * 100 + 1, 98, 98));
            }
        }
        DC.Close();

        double DPI_X = 96.0;
        double DPI_Y = 96.0;

        RenderTargetBitmap B = new RenderTargetBitmap(800, 800, DPI_X, DPI_Y, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        B.Render(D);
        theImage.Source = B;

Here is the XAML for the Image control:
<Image x:Name="theImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="800" Width="800"
                         Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />

First of all, am I even going about this the right way? The image is appearing correctly - just not being sized correctly.
Assuming this is the correct approach, how do I determine the screen DPI? The methods I have found online either return null or 96.
 

Does this answer your question? How can I get the DPI in WPF?

Why would you use an Image with RenderTargetBitmap at all, instead of staying with vector graphics and output the drawing by means of a VisualHost element or a DrawingImage?

Besides that, you should call D.RenderOpen() in a using block to save the explicit DC.Close() call.

It turns out that DPI had nothing to do with it - my parent DockPanel had both a hardcoded height of 800 and vertical alignment Stretch, which stretched everything to the parent window client height of 834.
